# Android Webview multitouch touchstart event not working with more than 2 fingers

Tags: javascript, android, webview, multi-touch

Consider the following code:

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    console.log('start');
});
```

When I tap with 2 fingers **at the same time** I have the following output (which is cool because is printed two times):

```
I/SnapScrollController(26508): setSnapScrollingMode case-default no-op
I/chromium(26508): [INFO:CONSOLE(69)] "start", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (69)
I/chromium(26508): [INFO:CONSOLE(69)] "start", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (69)
```

But when I use more than 2 fingers **at the same time** I had the same result, what am I doing wrong?
I was expected the log "start" as many times as fingers I was using.

In the other side `touchmove` and `touchend` works well.

I have uploaded the code [here](https://github.com/rchampa/dninja-project)

Comment: It is posible get 3 or more touches??

Comment: what happens if you log `event.touches.length` in your touchstart and touchmove event handlers? The problem might be that when you put our third finger down, you move one of the already touching fingers and cause the system to change to "moving" mode so it fires off touchmove events from then on.

Comment: @EdBallot I already have test when I place on the screen 2 fingers (at the same tine) and then one more, the result is the next fingers is printing their logs. My problem is I want to catch all 3,4 or 5 touchStartEvent placing fingers on the screen at same time. I update the question uploading code.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. What I saw testing with http://www.snappymaria.com/misc/TouchEventTest_v2.html on an ipad and a galaxyS5 is that both support >2 touch points in `touchstart`. On that page, it shows the length of `event.touches` so it would should something like
"touch start 2"
"touch start 3"
indicating that the first `touchstart` picked up my first two fingers and the second picked up the third finger.

Comment: @EdBallot Thanks to you:) You are right, I have test it on Sony Z2 and works well, but on my HTC One don't :(

Comment: I finally solved, its a misconfiguration on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my HTC One device.
Just turning on Magnification Gestures my device start to catch all events triggered with my fingers(more than two)

[image]